# xpages design elements not shown

Tags: xpages

I;m using IBM Notes 9 - social edition and I saw that some design elements are missing: for example, `paragraph` and `script editor`.

Should I import them or they are just hidden?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change your IBM Domino Designer preferences to show them in the palette. In Domino Designer go to `File - Preferences` and then go to `Domino Designer - XPages - Palette`.

[image]

Paragraph is in the Other Controls palette category while Output script is in the Core Controls palette category.